# In Thymeleaf, how do get href to link to part of page?

Tags: thymeleaf, href

In my Thymeleaf + Spring Boot project, I have a sidebar that has href link to part of sidebar (see code below).   The problem it wouldn't 'uncollapse' when click on it.   If I change it to href to outside (ie. www.yahoo.com) it works.   With thymeleaf, how do I get the href link to part of page to work?   Appreciate the help!

```
<li>
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#myLinks">
<i class="material-icons">image</i>
<p> Pages
<b class="caret"></b>
</p>
</a>

<div class="collapse" id="myLinks">
<ul class="nav">
<li>
<a th:href="@{http://www.yahoo.com}">
<span class="sidebar-mini"> Y </span>
<span class="sidebar-normal"> Yahoo </span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Have a look at the generated HTML code in the browser. Maybe you see the problem otherwise post it here

Comment: You use Bootstrap in your html page. Did you include the Bootstrap css and javascript libraries in your code?